# Add Build to TestFlight on IOS

Tags: ios, testflight

I upload my application to Itunes Connect using "Application Loader" It's successffuly uploaded and the build version appears in activity tab [image: in this Image]

but when trying to add any build to test it not appear in testflight tab [image: TestFlight Tab]

Moreover, when i navigate to testing group and try to add build nothing appear [image: Group Test]

P.S : My Application Developed using xamarin.form (Visual Studio on mac)

Answer (score 0):

Just wait for some time, App processing may take longer to process
have a look
http://www.brynbodayle.com/fixing-a-testflight-build-stuck-processing-in-itunes-connect/